# Selecting SSL_VERIFY_NONE for SSL_verify_mode

Tags: perl, ssl, xml-rpc, lwp

I am trying to create a client connection to an internal `ssl` site that does not have a certificate and needs to bypass the proxy.

I am able to bypass the proxy, and I am able to connect to the site and create a client connection, however, i am getting this ugly warning:

> ```
> *******************************************************************
>  Using the default of SSL_verify_mode of SSL_VERIFY_NONE for client
>  is deprecated! Please set SSL_verify_mode to SSL_VERIFY_PEER 
>  together with SSL_ca_file|SSL_ca_path for verification.
>  If you really don't want to verify the certificate and keep the
>  connection open to Man-In-The-Middle attacks please set
>  SSL_verify_mode explicitly to SSL_VERIFY_NONE in your application.
> *******************************************************************
> ```

at `C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 31`

My Code:

```
use    RPC::XML::Client;
use    XML::Simple;
use LWP::Protocol::https;

$ENV{NO_PROXY} = '10.*';

$ENV{'PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME'} = 0;

my $server = RPC::XML::Client->new("$vneUrl/api/index.ice",
                                 ssl_opts =>    { SSL_verify_mode   => 'SSL_VERIFY_NONE',
                                                 verify_hostname    => 0,   
                                                 SSL_use_cert => 0x00
                                               },
                                   );
```

Comment: Is there something in that warning that you do not understand?

Comment: It's not clear what the title of your post has to do with the rest of your question. Perhaps you could explain what you think the connection is?

Answer (score 20):

That message is from IO::Socket::SSL, and it refers to the constant `SSL_VERIFY_NONE` it exports rather than the string `'SSL_VERIFY_NONE'`.

Secondly, `ssl_opts` is an argument of LWP::UserAgent's constructor, not RPC::XML::Client's.

Try:

```
use IO::Socket::SSL qw( SSL_VERIFY_NONE );

RPC::XML::Client->new($uri,
   useragent => [
      ssl_opts => {
         verify_hostname => 0,
         SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
      },
   ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did eliminate the warning when creating the Client connection.,

Comment: Now that i have the $client created, i need to pass requests. such as [ my $session = $client->simple_request('login', 1, 0,$username, $password); ]   I'm once again getting the error for this statement. How would i go about passing the ssl_opts to each subsequent request?

Comment: hum, it uses the UserAgent object created in the constructor and to which those flags were passed as one would expect. Not sure where that message is coming from

Comment: Is there similar solution for [Net::SMTP::SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899327/how-to-set-ssl-certificate-for-gmail-smtp)?

Comment: @mpapec - I know this is an old comment, but I have had similar difficulty with Net::SMTP::SSL. The best solution I've found has been to use IO::Socket::SSL::set_defaults, whose settings will then be implicitly used by further Net::SMTP::SSL instances.

Comment: instead of using Net::SMTP::SSL or Net::SMTP::TLS I would suggest to use Net::SSLGlue::SMTP which combines the functionality of both modules by monkey patching Net::SMTP  and has proper SSL support, e.g. secure defaults

Answer (score 2):

New version I believe you should set to 0 or 1.
I think this was a bug:

```
500 SSL_verify_mode must be a number and not a string
```

From:

```
$useragent->ssl_opts(SSL_verify_mode=>'SSL_VERIFY_NONE');
```

To:

```
$useragent->ssl_opts(SSL_verify_mode=>'0');
```